# Slow internet connection on my Mac Mini

Tags: wifi, internet

Starting yesterday I'm dealing with low internet speed on my Mac; my download rate is 40 KB/S at the max. while my default download rate is 100 KB/S. I shut down my mac and tried another two PCs; the speed is my default and browsing is normal and I didn't encounter any slowness in my connection. So, I figured that the problem is on my Mac whether there's an application running update in the background or the App store updating (but the app store contains no update).

I need your help to find a way to track my internet usage so I may be able to terminate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Access Spotlight - either with `cmd + spacebar` or by clicking the magnifying icon on the right top corner of your screen
2. Search for **Activity Monitor**.
3. Select the far-right tab titled *Network* and you will find a description of all the network processes going on on your machine.

If there's a high network consumption process, you'll be able to spot it.